# Card drawing algorithm

Tags: algorithms, information-theory

I want to know whether there is an algorithm for randomly and securely drawing cards from a deck.

I was thinking about a way to play deck-based games online with no trusted party and no way to cheat.

More formally:

I want to find an algorithm, if possible, that allows player to take turns in drawing cards from a deck such that:

1. The cards drawn are random, and players can't influence the order
2. No player can have more information about his opponents cards and the cards left in the deck then it would have in a real world game (e.g.: when the deck is empty every player knows the other player cards anyway)

EDIT: I'll clarify some points (thanks to the comments):

I'm not interested in code, nor implementation details, but what I'm looking for is an algorithm, in its abstract description.

I'll write an example of what I'm looking for in the case of two decks of $N$ cards:

1. Each player choose a random permutation of [1..N]
2. He writes it down, hashes it, signs the hash, and passes the hash+signature to the other player
3. When a player must draw a card the other player chooses a number $i$ at random  ranging from 1 to the number of cards in the deck, the player then chooses the $i$-th number in his random permutation
4. At the end of the match the players exchange the original permutations, and check if the game was valid

Neither of the players can control the drawing order, and neither of them can cheat without being caught (signing the hash means that in case of dispute the player must provide the original shuffle) (for the actual game players would need to sign moves too, but that's beyond the point).

The problem is doing this with a single deck.

Comment: how... is this a mathematical problem?

Comment: how would you categorize it?

Comment: if you want help on securing your source of randomness(from inspection, predictions and modifications), probably [security.se]; if you want help looking up the right library calls, try seaching on [so]. If you want help on a shuffling algorithm, [so] should point you to the Fisher-Yates algorithm.

Comment: or, is that you lack a central server to act as an authority, and yet you want every attempt at tweaking the rolls to be detected or subverted by the other party?

Comment: If you want to protect the server rolls from man-in-the-middle attacks, [security.se] seems like an appropriate place to look for an answer

Comment: This seems to me like a perfectly reasonable question about mathematical cryptography.  The question is to devise a protocol that allows two parties to generate a sequence of pseudorandom numbers without either party having undue influence over the generated sequence.  One basic method would be for the two parties to first agree on a [pseudorandom number generation algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator), and then use a [key agreement protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_agreement_protocol) to choose a [seed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_seed).

Comment: (continued)  Of course, that would have the problem that both parties could "peek ahead" at the psuedorandom sequence once the key is established.  Also, it seems possible that either party could try to game the key-agreement protocol in a way that would produce a favorable random sequence of numbers.

Comment: @JanDvorak yeah, my question is about finding an algorithm than can be used without a TTP and without players being able to influence the outcome

Comment: @JimBelk exactly, I would like something that isn't peekable and that doesn't give info to one party on what the other party has drawn

Comment: I'm not concerned with man-in-the-middle, I can assume I have a perfect source of randomness if needed, and I'm not talking about code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mental_poker) on "mental poker" describes such an algorithm. It's a bit complicated, but that's only to be expected.

Comment: @miniBill: Thank you for accepting my answer! If your intention was to award me the bounty too, then you have to do this separately. (I have made this mistake myself in the past.)

Comment: I had to wait for some hours before being able to award it :)